# Trying to perform an SFTP upload and getting strange error line

Tags: php, ssh, sftp

I have this code trying to upload a test file into a SFTP server

```
$strServer = "**********";
$strServerPort = "**";
$strServerUsername = "*********";
$strServerPassword = "********";
$csv_filename = "test.csv";
$resConnection = ssh2_connect($strServer, $strServerPort);

if(ssh2_auth_password($resConnection, $strServerUsername, $strServerPassword)){
    //Initialize SFTP subsystem

    echo "connecting to server";

    $resSFTP = ssh2_sftp($resConnection);    


    $resFile = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$resSFTP/".$csv_filename, 'w');
    $srcFile = fopen($csv_filename, 'r');
    $writtenBytes = stream_copy_to_stream($srcFile, $resFile);
    fclose($resFile);
    fclose($srcFile);
} else {
    echo "error connecting";
}
```

The error I get is

> fopen(ssh2.sftp://Resource id #3/test.txt): failed to open stream:

Could someone please assist?

Comment: Wait. The value of `$resSFTP` is `Resource id #3`? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thats what I thought. I have no idea where that is coming from myself, yet thats what the error is stating. This is a clients remote server I am connecting to as they want a file loaded each day. This is the test

Comment: Apparently your code has no problem. What is your PHP version, web server & OS?

Comment: @Raptor it totally makes sense as [`ssh2_sftp()`](http://php.net/manual/function.ssh2-sftp.php#refsect1-function.ssh2-sftp-returnvalues) returns a _resource_.

Comment: @Raptor PHP version 5.6. I am using in a Cron job

Comment: Always worth reading the comments on the manual page ~ http://php.net/manual/function.ssh2-sftp.php#121200

Comment: I researched that if i change $resFile = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$resSFTP/".$csv_filename, 'w'); with $resFile = fopen("ssh2.sftp://".. intval($resSFTP)."/".$csv_filename, 'w'); It works. I have no error just awaiting confirmation from the client they received the file